# Logo image in the center of a menu doesnt sit right

Tags: html, css, positioning

Ok so i have searched through probably 50 or so threads here on SO and cant find a solution yet. i have a navigation bar that is 1000px wide by 47px tall. i have a logo that is 135px tall and 167px wide. i want this image to sit dead center on the menu and extend above it. the image has the angled design i want to connect to the edges of the menu on either side. here is a mockup of what i would like for it to look like vs how it looks now.

[image: Mockup + Current Screenshot]

My CSS:

```
.masthead {
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url(../img/rmr-masthead.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
/* == Nav Menu == */
.ribbon {
    width: 1000px;
    max-height: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px!important;
    background: #bd7d4c;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#bd7d4c), to(#7a4520));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bd7d4c, #7a4520);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bd7d4c, #7a4520);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bd7d4c, #7a4520);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bd7d4c, #7a4520);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bd7d4c 0%, #7a4520 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}  
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: -1em;
    border: 1.5em solid #754a15;
    z-index: -1;
}
.ribbon:before {
    left: -2em;
    border-right-width: 1.5em;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
}
.ribbon:after {
    right: -2em;
    border-left-width: 1.5em;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before, .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
    border-color: #66320f transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: -1em;
    content:'';
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
    left: 0;
    border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
    right: 0;
    border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
.nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 901px;
    height: 0;
}
.nav li {
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
.nav li a {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-shadow: #493724 0 -1px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #6b3700;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(212, 154, 91, 0.49);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(212, 154, 91, 0.49);
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(212, 154, 91, 0.49);
}
.nav li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #6b3700;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(212, 154, 91, 0.49);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(212, 154, 91, 0.49);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(212, 154, 91, 0.49);
}
.nav li a:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #c3885b;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c3885b 0%, #905226 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #c3885b), color-stop(100%, #905226));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3885b 0%, #905226 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c3885b 0%, #905226 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c3885b 0%, #905226 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3885b 0%, #905226 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#c3885b', endColorstr='#905226', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
    /* before hack */
    content:".";
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.nav li a:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
.ribbon img {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 167px;
    height: 117px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My HTML

```
<div class="masthead">
</div>

<div class="ribbon">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><span class="navhover"></span><a href="index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><span class="navhover"></span><a href="about">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><span class="navhover"></span><a href="about">About Bison</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <img src="./img/logo-nav.png">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><span class="navhover"></span><a href="recipies">Recipies</a>
        </li>
        <li><span class="navhover"></span><a href="products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><span class="navhover"></span><a href="contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "margin: 0;" in your css ".ribbon img" cancel "margin-top: -100px;" above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin: 0;` in your css `.ribbon img` cancel `margin-top: -100px;` above. So simply remove `margin: 0;` like this:

```
.ribbon img {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 167px;
    height: 117px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Or to be a little more pedantic, `margin: -100px 0 0`, just to retain margin 0 elsewhere :)

Comment: I think that default margins for <img> tag are 0. Maybe i am wrong though.

Comment: I was scrolling through old questions on here and noticed i forgot to reply thanks for the answer. Im usually not so rude lol. Anyhow, long overdue but thank you very much. this did solve the issue for me. sometimes you stare at the same code for hours and still overlook the simple stupid error!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to set a negative margin-top on logo-nav.png (i'd do it inline on an img tag, personally), might also have to set the z-index so the image is above everything else (if it isn't already).